# Synthesizing vowel from existing audio sample jin matlab

Tags: matlab, audio, filtering, speech-synthesis, phonetics

I'm using matlab and have a recorded sample of a vowel sound.
I'm looking to make use of my existing sample to synthesize a vowel sound at a pitch of 150Hz (lasting 5 seconds). [I originally thought that I'd just have to take a sample of my existing vowel sound at the given frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896992/selecting-part-of-a-sample-by-frequency) but, obviously, that doesn't actually work.

So, now, I'm pretty stumped on how one would actually go about synthesizing the vowel sound?

Comment: So you have a sample of the vowel at a known pitch and just want to change the pitch?

Comment: @LuisMendo: Not really, I'm looking to create a synthetic vowel from the spectral envelope of my existing sample. (The eventual intention is to generate a simple tune)

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach is:

1. Take a single period of the sample (identified visually). It is important that it begins and ends at 0 value (or very close) to avoid cracking noises caused by discintinuities at the each endpoints.
2. Upsample or downsample the waveform extracted in step 1 period as necessary to get the desired pitch. Upsampling decreases pitch, downsampling increases it. You can use `resample` function for instance.
3. Patch a lot of those periods one after the other until you get the desired duration of 5 seconds. You can use `repmat` function for that.
4. Multiply that 5-second waveform element-by-element by a time-envelope with the desired shape. The envelope shape will typically be a fast attack in the form of a linear ramp from 0 to 1 , then a long constant value and then a decreasing ramp towards 0.

For increased realism you could introduce slow amplitude variations in the "constant" part of the envelope (tremolo effect). You could also extract in step 1 a piece of signal containing not one but several periods of the waveform. Those periods will not be exactly the same, and that will add "warmth" to the sound.